# Create a numerical df in r using factor df

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a factor df that I would like it to be need it to be numerical/dummy. I used as.integer to each column and then made a cbind to the original data frame. Is there a way to do all columns at once?

```
data <- data.frame(
  x = c('a','b','c'),
  y = c('d','e','f'),
  z = c('g','h','i'),
  stringsAsFactors = TRUE
)

x_factor <- as.integer(data$x)
y_factor <- as.integer(data$y)
z_factor <- as.integer(data$z)

data_binded <- cbind(a,x_factor,y_factor,z_factor)
```

Comment: You can do `data[paste0(names(data), "_factor")] <- lapply(data, as.integer)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is dplyr solution:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(across(ends_with("factor"), as.numeric))
```

```
  x y z x_factor y_factor z_factor
1 a d g        1        1        1
2 b e h        2        2        2
3 c f i        3        3        3
```